# Header component not change React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stack-navigator

I'm facing an issue in which [header component](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/header/) does not change. It's same on all the screen even if I have defined separately in [Stacknavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack) navigationOptions.

```
<Header
  leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#fff' }}
  centerComponent={{ text: 'MY TITLE', style: { color: '#fff' } }}
  rightComponent={{ icon: 'home', color: '#fff' }}
/>
```

Even if I have added in each screen separately but it's showing home (first header component) as attached.

[image: Home screen][image: Home screen with menu][image: Another view of some sort]

I have also override navigation options on each screen as well but same header issue.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
   title: 'User List',
   headerTitle:'User List',
   headerTintColor :'#ffffff',
 });
```

Below is my complete code

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
              Login: {
                screen: LoginScreen,
                navigationOptions: {
                  header: null,
                  headerMode: 'none'
                }
              },

              Home: {
                screen: AppDrawerNavigation,
                navigationOptions: ({
                  navigation
                }) => ({
                  header: < Header
                  outerContainerStyles={{ backgroundColor: '#1999CE' }}
                  leftComponent = {                                
                   <Icon name='menu'  color='#ffffff' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')}/>
                 }
                  centerComponent = {
                                  {
                                      text: 'Home',
                                      style: {
                                          color: '#fff'
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                rightComponent = {
                  {
                    icon: 'home',
                    color: '#fff'
                  }
                }
                />,

              }),
      },


      WebViews: {
        screen: AppDrawerNavigation,
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null,
          headerMode: 'none'
        }
      },


      Profile: {
        screen: ProfileScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#1999CE',
          }, 
        }
      },
      UserList :{
        screen:AppDrawerNavigation,

        navigationOptions: ({
          navigation
        }) => ({

          title: 'List User',
          headerTitle:'List User',
          header: < Header
          outerContainerStyles={{ backgroundColor: '#1999CE' }}
          leftComponent = {                                
           <Icon name='menu'  color='#ffffff' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')}/>

         }
         centerComponent = {
          {
            text: 'List User',
            style: {
              color: '#fff'
            }
          }
        }
        rightComponent = {
          {
            icon: 'home',
            color: '#fff'
          }
        }
        />,

      }),
      }
    },
    {         navigationOptions: {
              headerMode: 'screen'
            },

    }
    );

const AppDrawerNavigation = DrawerNavigator({

              Home: {
                screen: HomeScreen,


              },

              WebViews: {
                screen: WebViewScreen,
              },
              UserList: {
                screen: UserListScreen,

              },
            },
            {
             navigationOptions: {
              headerMode: 'none'
            },
            drawerPosition: 'left',
            drawerWidth: 200,
            contentOptions: {
              activeTintColor: '#000000',
              activeTintColor :'#ffffff',
              activeBackgroundColor :'#1999CE',
              inactiveTintColor :'#1999CE',
              inactiveBackgroundColor :'#ffffff',
            }
          }

          );
```

Can you suggest a possible fix that would address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withHeaders` from this package [react-navigation-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-utils) to make custom headers for each screen.

Comment: Thanks for reply if you can provide solution for [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/header/) that would be helpful instead of chaning library

Comment: It is a library used to add a header to react-navigation. It's different from react-native-elements.

Comment: You can use `Header` from `react-native-elements` with `react-navigation-utils`.

Comment: I know but i wanted to use react-native-elements library not another one

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Home: {
            screen: HomeScreen,
           navigationOptions: {
              title:'Home',}
          },

          WebViews: {
            screen: WebViewScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
               title:'Web Views',}
          },
          UserList: {
            screen: UserListScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
            title:'User List',}
          },
```

hope it'll hepls you....